# C# Object referenced in different forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a button with a Mouse Click event. I want this button with it's appearance and it's event code the same on all forms.

Is there anyway to have a library type item you can define once and then reference it on other forms. Right now when I make a change I have to update the button on all forms.

Notes: When I show a form, I hide() the previous form so the forms this button appears on are never open together.

Comment: Yes, you  can create a myButton class that inherits from Button and does all you want to do.

Comment: @user1887198: What are you using `WPF` or `WinForms`? It matters.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is inherit from a `Button` class and then use your custom button class instead of `Button`.

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public CustomButton() : base()
    {
        // Set custom properties, event hooks, etc. here
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome,  so once I great the button class I am a little confused as to what the syntax look like when I call custom class in each form. I am used to dropping a button from the tool box.. how do I call the custom class code so it shows up in the design editor.

Comment: @user1887198 If it's part of your project, then you'll see it in the toolbox once you build your solution.  If it's part of a library you created, just right click Toolbox, click on choose items and browse for it.

Comment: @user1887198 If it solved your issue, make sure to mark it as an answer.